# Objective-C condition that only applies if other condition is met

Tags: objective-c, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm learning Objective-C and I need to build a program where there are two "people" playing a game. To win the game one person must be above 21 points and must have a lead of at least 2 points. I can't figure out how to write that condition.

```
while (plyrOnePts <= 21 || plyrTwoPts <= 21) && 
(abs(plyrOnePts - plyrTwoPts) <= 2)) {

}
```

That is what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using separate variables for every thing. If it is possible try to bundle related stuff in objects.

Once you do that you can easily achieve your goal by writing a method in player class,

> Player.h

```
@interface Player:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger points;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger lead;

- (BOOL) playerDidWin;
```

> Player.m

```
@implementation Player {
- (BOOL) playerDidWin {
   if(self.points > 21 && self.lead >= 2) {
       NSLog("Congrats %@ won the match", self.name);
       //Game Over.
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Although you don't need *points* to be in h file, it can be private since you don't want other objects to access that property. Also the *lead* property needs to be calculated by other object, something like manager class or so.

Answer (score 0):

You really should show your code, describe what you've tried, and why it is failing. Remember that for future questions or you'll just get down-voted (as you have been at the time I'm writing this) and no answers.

That said let's see if we can point you in the right direction. You appear to have a `while` statement, so something like:

```
while (not won condition)
{
   // keep playing
}
```

and you are stuck on the *not won condition*. Well you should have learnt that there are comparison operators; such as *greater than*, `>`; which you can use for a condition with a single test. You also should know you can combine conditions, aka *boolean values*, with the boolean operators; such as *and*, `&&`. Finally "not" is another boolean operator which operates on a single value and can be simply applied to your "won condition".

If you don't know what comparison or boolean operators are stop now and go read some documentation!

So what is your won condition?

> One person must be above 21 points

In English that is:

> (first person's score is greater than 21 points) or (second person's is greater than 21 points)

Convert that to variable references (for the two scores), comparison operators (the greater than's), and a boolean operator (the or) and you have a condition. However you have a second requirement:

> and must have a lead of at least 2 points

Well the lead is the difference in scores:

> first person's score minus second person's score

However that will be negative if it is the second person is ahead. To address that we use a function to calculate the *absolute value*, which is simply the magnitude of the number ignoring the sign. So what you need is:

> absolute value of (first person's score minus second person's score)

Search the documentation for the absolute value function, convert to variable references, and insert the minus operator.

Now we've already covered how to compare so we'll skip spelling out the test for the difference being at least 2 points. How to combine the two conditions; the score being greater than 21 and the lead being at least two. Well the clue is in the English: *and*. Above we used *or*, there is also a boolean *and* operator.

Put it all together and you will have solved your problem.

HTH

Comment: I updated my question with my current code that I couldn't get to work.

Comment: Your added code has the condition wrong: the condition is true, and the loop will continue, only if *either* players score is less than or equal to 21 *and* the two scores are within 2 of each other. Compare that to what I spelled out in the answer and you'll see it is not the same. You've got the general idea, just need to tweak it, have another go!

Answer (score 0):

```
while (game) {

if ((player1.score>=21)&&(player1.score-player2.score>=2)) // player1 win
if ((player2.score>=21)&&(player2.score-player1.score>=2)) // player2 win

}
```